# file not uploading after htaccess redirect

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, file-upload

So file uploading was actually working fine initially, but in order to protect my PHP files I did URL rewrite in htaccess and the file uploading has stopped ever since... I removed the htaccess redirect rule and it began working again.
Please come to my aid because I really need to hide the actual directory to my PHP files.

**javascript ajax request**

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("file_name", file);
AJAX_REQUEST.open("POST", " https://my_site.com/testFile", true);
AJAX_REQUEST.send(form);
```

**htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine   On 
RewriteCond     %{HTTPS}      off
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$        https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteRule     ^testFile     https:///my_site.com/phps/validateFile.php    [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your `RewriteRule` missing the `$`?

```
# should this
RewriteRule     ^testFile     https:///my_site.com/phps/validateFile.php    [NC,L]

# be this?
RewriteRule     ^testFile$    https:///my_site.com/phps/validateFile.php    [NC,L]
```